# Proving that a minimal set satisfying 'tree' properties is countable.

Tags: set-theory

Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal F (X)$ dentoe the finite subsets of $X$ and let there be given a function

$$\tag 1 F: X \to \mathcal F (X)$$

Let $K$ be a finite subset of $X$.

Definition: A subset $Y$ of $X$ is said to be an inductive accommodation of $K$ and $F$ if

$$\tag 2 K \subset Y$$
$$\tag 3 \text{For every } y \in Y, \; F(y) \subset Y$$

The intersection of any family of subsets  of $X$ that are inductive accommodations of $K$ and $F$ is also an inductive accommodation.

> Prove that the minimal inductive accommodation of $K$ and $F$ is a countable set.

**My work**

I was looking at

[Generating all coprime pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Generating_all_coprime_pairs)

and

[Tree of primitive Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples)

and figured that this abstraction is true but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @bof thanks - fixing now

Comment: I'd proceed by defining a sequence $Y_n$ of sets and trying to show that $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty Y_n$ is an inductive accommodation of $K$ and $F$ and is countable.

Comment: I'd try to define that so that $K\subseteq Y_0$ and so that $y\in Y_n\implies F(y)\subseteq Y_{n+1}$.

Comment: @bof and it is east to show $ \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty Y_n$ can be constructed to be minimal.

Comment: Indeed, but in any case, if one inductive accommodation is countable, that shows that the minimul inductive accommodation is countable. The hypotheses seem excessive. $K$ could be countable, and $F(x)$ could be countable.

Comment: @bof So you have to use some choice; such trees are a world apart from the axiom of infinity in ZFC.

Answer (score 1):

Following bof's suggestions...

For any $Y \subset X$ we can form $\Phi (Y)$,

$$\tag 1 \Phi (Y) =  \bigcup_{y \in Y} F(y)$$

If $Y$ is countable so is $\Phi (Y)$,

Let $Y_0 = K$ and for $n \ge 0$ define

$$\tag 2 Y_{n+1} = \Phi (Y_n)$$

By induction. each $Y_n$ is countable, so

$$\tag 3 \hat K = \bigcup_{n \ge 0} Y_n$$

is also countable.

Claim: $\hat K$ is an inductive accommodation of $K$ and $F$:

Clearly $K \subset \hat K$.

If $y \in \hat K$ then there is a $k$ with $y \in Y_k$, and since

$$\tag 4 F(y) \subset  \Phi (Y_k) = Y_{k+1} \subset \hat K$$

the claim is established.

It can be demonstrated by induction that $\hat K$ is the minimal inductive accommodation .

Note that we need the axiom of choice in this setting.